# If the sides $a, b, c $ form a successive geometric progression with common ratio $r(r>1)$, then prove that $A<B<\frac{\pi}{3}<C$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

From the given data, the obvious result that can be drawn is

$$b^2=ac$$

Also $$\cos B =\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$$
$$\cos B =\frac{a^2+c^2}{2b^2}-\frac{b^2}{2b^2}$$
$$\cos B =\frac{(a+c)^2}{2b^2}-1-\frac 12$$

I don’t know how to proceed.

Comment: Replace $b^2$ by $ac$ and show that $\cos{B} - \frac{1}{2} > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so closeee

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a^{2}+c^{2}-b^{2}}{2ac}&=\frac{a^{2}+c^{2}-ac}{2ac}\\
&>\frac{2ac-ac}{2ac}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus $\angle A<\angle B < \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $>\frac{-2ac-ac}{2ac}$? Ofc, that wouldn’t work, but $a^2+c^2=(a+c)^2-2ac$

Comment: $a^{2}+c^{2}>2ac$ from $(a-c)^{2}>0$

Answer (score 0):

According to the sine rule, the geometric progression implies

$$\sin^2 B = \sin A \sin C = \frac12( \cos(A-C) + \cos B )$$

which leads to

$$2\cos^2 B + \cos B -2 = -\cos(A-C)>-1$$

or

$$(2\cos B -1)(\cos B +1) > 0\implies \cos B > \frac12$$

which yields $B < \frac\pi3$. Thus,  $A<B<\frac{\pi}{3}<C$.